# Using BroadcastReceiver and registerReceiver in android kotlin to get an mms and pass values

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, mms

I can't seem to use `BroadcastReceiver()` to get mms data without `Cursor()` so I tried to use a workaround with `ComponentActivity()` and `registerReceiver()`. Does anyone know how to do this with Kotlin? I really need to pass parts of the mms data by passing values to another function. I can't use this to register the class in the manifest. Is that the problem?

```
    package radwil.sms.routing

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.*
import android.database.Cursor
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.Telephony.Sms.Intents.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED_ACTION
import android.text.TextUtils
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import radwil.sms.utils.log
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.InputStreamReader

/**
 * This class used to monitor SMS
 */
class MmsReceiverK: ComponentActivity() {

   // this is the second problem's solution for now
   @SuppressLint("Range")
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

      val receiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
         override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            log( "+++++inside receiver")
         }
      }

      val filterMMS = IntentFilter.create("android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED", "application/vnd.wap.mms-message")
      registerReceiver(receiver, filterMMS)
      filterMMS.priority = IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY
      filterMMS.addAction(WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED_ACTION) // MMS

      if (TextUtils.equals(intent.action, WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED_ACTION)) {
         //handle the WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED_ACTION

         val contentResolver: ContentResolver = this.contentResolver
         val projection = arrayOf("_id", "ct_t", "Address")
         val uri: Uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/")
         val query: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)
         if (query != null) {
            if (query.moveToFirst()) {
               do {

                  // my second problem is an empty query.getColumnIndex?
                  val string: String = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex("ct_t"))

                  if ("application/vnd.wap.multipart.related" == string) {
                     // mms
                     val mmsId = query.getColumnIndex("_id")
                     val mmsAddress = query.getColumnIndex("Address")
                     val body = getMmsText(mmsId)

                     log(
                        "received SMS from: $mmsAddress" +
                              "with message: $body"
                     )

                  } else {
                     // sms
                  // return?
                  }
               } while (query.moveToNext())
            }
            query.close()
         }

      }
   }

   // parsing "part" for text of message

   private fun getMmsText(id: Int): String {
      val partURI = Uri.parse("content://mms/part/$id")
      var `is`: InputStream? = null
      val sb = StringBuilder()
      try {
         `is` = this.contentResolver.openInputStream(partURI)
         if (`is` != null) {
            val isr = InputStreamReader(`is`, "UTF-8")
            val reader = BufferedReader(isr)
            var temp: String = reader.readLine()
            while (true) {
               sb.append(temp)
               temp = reader.readLine()
            }
         }
      } catch (e: IOException) {
      } finally {
         if (`is` != null) {
            try {
               `is`.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
            }
         }
      }
      return sb.toString()
   }

}
```